# How to force ssh to execute bash instead of the user default on the remote machine?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to execute a bash script with ssh but when I try this it's using ksh which is the user's default shell.

I can't change that default.

So, how can I trick ssh to execute my script with bash instead of the default shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make this the [first line of your script](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

*Edit*: As per [this](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#env), the utility of `/usr/bin/env` is dubious.  So, you probably want:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Replace `/bin/bash` with the actual path of `bash` executable.

Comment: i added this line then it doesnt execute script :S

Comment: @soField: Try with my edit, or try tangens method.  You must make sure `bash` is installed on the server.

Comment: Do you know where bash is installed on the server?  As tangens said, it would be `ssh user@host bash command.sh`.  If you want to use my method, you need to make the first line `#!<path of bash>`, where you replace `<path of bash>` by the actual `bash` executable's full path: it could be `/bin/bash`, `/usr/bin/bash`, or something else.

Comment: i think the problem is my command has " character , it may cause a problem is there any way to execute command with ssh 
which contains " chars in it

Comment: Why do you have a command with `"` in it?  `ssh user@host 'com\"mand arg'` may work.

Answer (score 3):

You can call your script explicitly with bash:

```
ssh <ssh-opts> bash <scriptname>
```

This way there will be a ksh executed at login, but inside ksh you start a bash executing your script.